# importing data from non-wordpress mysql db

Tags: custom-field, database, mysql, post-meta, import

I have created an import file to get the articles from a non-wordpress db and bring them in as posts in wordpress, I am not sure how to bring over the thumbnail image into my custom field I defined as "thumbnail". Any suggestions.

Here is the code I am using:

```
    $results = mysql_query("SELECT headline, abstract, article, author, posted,    category, img, facilities FROM articles",$lclink);

    $i = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
   $post = array();
   $post['post_status'] = 'publish';
   $post['post_category'] = array(1);
   $post['post_date'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($row['posted']));
   $post['post_title'] = $row['headline'];
   $post['post_excerpt'] = $row['abstract'];
   $post['post_content'] = $row['article'];
   $post['post_author'] = $row['author'];



   $posts[$i] = $post;
   $i++;
}

require('./wp-load.php');

foreach ($posts as $post) {
  wp_insert_post($post);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to get the ID back from your post insertion and use that with `add_post_meta`:

```
$post_id = wp_insert_post($post);
add_post_meta($post_id, 'thumbnail', $yourvalue, true);
```

Comment: So the code you gave should work to assign the retrieved data once I have it, any suggestions on writing the code for actually retrieving that data from the existing database?

Comment: @Pete - is the field in that original query? you could just do all of the work in that first while loop rather than building the $posts array and looping through that separately.

Comment: ok, I'll give it a try